# DictVectorizer learns more features for the training set

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have the following code which works as expected:

```
clf = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', DictVectorizer(sparse=False)),
    ('classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy'))
])

clf.fit(X[:size], y[:size])

score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

I wanted to do the same logic without using Pipeline:

```
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)

Xdv = v.fit_transform(X[:size])
Xdv_test = v.fit_transform(X_test)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(Xdv[:size], y[:size])

clf.score(Xdv_test, y_test)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 8251 and input n_features is 14303
```

It seems that DictVectorizer learns more features for the test set than for the training set. I want to know how does Pipeline handle this issue and how can I accomplish the same.

Comment: You should use the vectorizer you fit to your training set on your test set instead of fitting it a second time i.e. `Xdv_test = v.transform(X_test)`. Also, how are you splitting `X` and `X_test`? And why do you need the `[:size]` only for `X`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont call `fit_transform` again.

Do this:

```
Xdv_test = v.transform(X_test)
```

When you do `fit()` or `fit_transform()`, the dict vectorizer will forget the features learnt during previous call (on training data) and re-fits again, hence different number of features.

Pipeline will automatically handle the test data appropriately when you do `clf.score(X_test, y_test)` on the pipeline.